# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Im try to put my laravel aplication to online host, for front end its work try it on ajibb.com, but when im try login to admin not work, for localhost work with nice. when im try open admin i got error :

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 755
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 57
```

whats wrong can point me out which part should i set, for url www.ajibb.com/admin. thanks

Comment: I guess that, it wasn't only for admin url. Other routes still problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should have something like this set in your routes file:

```
Route::get( 'admin', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getIndex', // point to your admin controller
    'as'  => 'admin.index' // give your route an optional name
]);
```

Or just test it with

```
Route::get( 'admin', function() { return 'works!' });
```

Answer (score 0):

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection** is thrown when the referred link is not available in `route.php` file.

Make sure your link is available in `route.php`

```
Route::get( 'admin', function() {
return 'your admin view';
 });
```

If you use a Controller,

```
Route::get( 'admin','your admin controller@index'); //assuming you used default
```

Answer (score 0):

If it working fine on localhost, i'm pretty sure there is something missing on your server. In my experienced before there was missing php-xml plugin, if so you must install it. I assume you're running ubuntu server and php 7 then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Or if its already installed, make sure it enabled in `php.ini` configuration.

Comment: I don't think this is not a solution. I might be wrong. But, he described that admin login problem. Then, how do you know he using php7 version? Then, if he using Centos, how?

Comment: Faced the same issue and fine myself that was problem with HTTP request.  I didn't know what version php is, just assume it. if other version just change `php[version]-xml`. If it centos just using `yum` instead of `apt-get`.